# GlassFish V3 File Upload Servlet, file access problem

Tags: configuration, file-upload, glassfish-3, access-denied

I have more of a structure or permissions problem than an actual coding problem I am trying to upload a file in the most secure way possible without going down the route of inserting it into a database.

I am finding that when I try and store a file outside of the application on the server my application is being denied access to the directories.

I have no experience with GlassFish configuration and would welcome any solutions you can give.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple I was using the org.apache.commons.fileUpload package and specifying my own temporary directory by allowing Java to enquire of the system where to store temporary files the problem was removed.

Left here that this post may help others.